# SQL Server Import Wizard "workgroup information file" error when importing Access .mdb

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to import an MS Access. mdb file into SQLExpress if I do not have MS Access installed?  Reason I ask is because I am getting the following error when attempting to use the Import Wizard in SQL Management Studio to perform this task:

"Test connection failed because of an error initializing provider.  Cannot start your application.  The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the .mdb file is encrypted with user-level security then you need to provide the SQL Server import wizard with

1. the username and password to connect to the database, and
2. the location of the Workgroup Information file (.mdw)

In the SQL Server import wizard, click the "Advanced" button...

[image: Advanced.png]

... and then on the "Connection" tab

- un-check "Blank password"
- check "Allow saving password"
- enter the "User name" and "Password"

[image: Connection.png]

On the "All" tab, select the "Jet OLEDB:System database" property and click the "Edit Value..." button...

[image: SystemDatabase.png]

...then enter the full path to the associated .mdw file

[image: MdwPath.png]

After saving the changes you should be able to proceed with the import to SQL Server as usual.

Comment: What about having no directory (uls), nor a file like: d:\Users\Public\uls\Security.mdw ?

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I just removed the database password and that worked for me.