# access .mdb Not a valid file name.

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010, database-connection, connection-string

My program needs to connect to old access database .mdb using c#.
I have a trouble deploying the program.

Here is the scenario:

- all Machine were tested with access database engine x84bit and x64
- all machine are 64bit operating system  All sum.mdb has the same directory
- Development machine: No error - tested with all bit types of office
- Client A machine with office 64bit: No Error
- Client B machine with office 32bit: No Error
- Client C machine with office 64bit: Error: Not a valid file name
- Client D machine with office 32bit: Error: Not a valid file name

Here is the Error on C and D machines 
[image]

I tried using .udl to detect the .mdb file but shows this error

[image]
[image]

Here is my connection string

```
accessProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
accessDatasource =  file.ReadToEnd() + "\\" + "SUM.mdb" ;
accessPassword = "samplePassword";

accessString = @"Provider=" + accessProvider + "; " +
             "Data Source=" + accessDatasource + "; " +
             "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + accessPassword + ";";
            MessageBox.Show(accessString);
```

[image]

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495393/sql-server-import-wizard-workgroup-information-file-error-when-importing-acces)

Answer (score 0):

1 week before I posted the question I had searched all forums and blogs I encounter but to no success. An hour after I posted this question then the answer came up.

It seems that the file I am accessing for the directory had some hidden newline ([enter] or \n or another line below the directory text) on the client machines C and D.

I tried displaying the connection but the message box doesn't show the new line. The oleconnection seems to detect the new line and displaying invalid path.