# Import and export wizard error when trying to import MS Access database into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, import

My MS Access database is password protected and I work as it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22500754/8736671

but it throws an error that the workgroup file information file is missing or opened exclusively an other user.

Answer (score 0):

open ms access go to file> option click on general change User name and Initials as Admin and close all files and restart PC now repeat the steps,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22500754/8736671